# What means double deed?

Tags: idioms

In *Adventures of Tom Sawyer*, there is a dialogue going on between Tom and Becky:
- Yes I do, indeed I do. Please let me.
- You'll tell.
- No I won't—**deed and deed and double deed** won't.
- You won't tell anybody at all.

Vividly she is promising, but I want to know what that means exactly?

Comment: indeed and indeed and double indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*deed* should really be written as *'deed* . It's short for "indeed"

So, what she's actually saying is:

> No I won't - indeed and indeed and double indeed [I] won't.

As such, what she's meaning is that she's making a stern assertion that she won't tell if Tom allows her to do it.

It's a method of emphasizing what she's saying.