# The man of double deed

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

There is [this beautiful poem I heard on "The Fall" (british tv show)](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/56374/the-man-of-double-deed).

> There was a man of **double deed**,
> Who sowed his garden full of seed;
> When the seed began to grow,
> 'Twas like a garden full of snow;
> When the snow began to melt,
> 'Twas like a ship without a belt;
> When the ship began to sail,
> 'Twas like a bird without a tail;
> When the bird began to fly,
> 'Twas like an eagle in the sky;
> When the sky began to roar,
> 'Twas like a lion at my door;
> When my door began to crack,
> 'Twas like a stick across my back;
> When my back began to smart,
> 'Twas like a penknife in my heart;
> And when my heart began to bleed,
> 'Twas death, and death, and death indeed.

What does "man of double deed" mean? I guess it has some negative connotation, like a person leading double life, being double-faced, hypocritical, etc. But maybe I'm wrong.

The assumption is based on the fact that the poem is cited by the double-faced antagonist of the show.

Comment: it just mean two deeds, and it's used for rhyming here. I don't think one can ascribe a particular meaning to it. As for belt, I haven't heard of a ship's belt and I'm rather attuned to nautical meanings....

Comment: All I can think of is a safety belt? In  modern terms, something by which you hook yourself via a line to a mast or other part of a sailing ship.

Comment: @Lambie, the poem is couple of centuries old, there probably was some particular meaning for the belt, aside from something to hook yourself to a mast, because ship without that kind of belt would be completely alright I guess :) Thanks for the resopnse though!

Comment: ...note that there's an alternative (probably, *earlier*) version of the poem that starts with [*A **man of words and not of deeds** \ Is like a garden full of weeds*.](http://www.rhymes.org.uk/a4-a-man-of-words.htm)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, yes, I saw that version on the web too. There's no question about menaning of this one )) Maybe the connotation remained after the words had been changed?

Comment: @r2r23 I looked at terminology and sites that deal with the sailing ships of yore. I  could not find anything. The deeds and weeds thing, however, sounds plausible.

Comment: Noting [*The links and repetitions seem governed partly by rhyme and **partly by some obsessive, hyperrational formula of causality***](http://www.slate.com/articles/arts/poem/2008/11/there_was_a_man_of_double_deed.html), I wouldn't spend too much time thinking about what it "means". I see it as something of a "nonsense ditty", but if it appeals to you it can mean pretty much whatever you want it to mean.

Comment: Belt armor is a layer of heavy metal armor plated onto or within the outer hulls of warships, typically on battleships, battlecruisers and cruisers, and aircraft carriers.

The belt armor is designed to prevent projectiles from penetrating to the heart of a warship. When struck by an artillery shell or underwater torpedo, the belt armor either absorbs the impact and explosion with its sheer thickness and strength, or else uses sloping to redirect the projectile and its blast downwards.
The main armor belt covers the warship from its main deck down to some distance below the waterline.

Comment: I suggest that "double deed" might mean duplicitous, deceptive, unfaithful, "serving two masters", like a double agent... that sort of thing. Someone said similar here in a comment: https://robertpinsky.wordpress.com/2013/12/04/anon-doubledeed/comment-page-1/

Comment: My first guess would be that a “man of double deed” is one notable for two accomplishments, or two distinct skills.

Answer (score -1):

According to a brief discussion on another question ([What means double deed?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122008/what-means-double-deed)) "double deed" is a contraction of "double indeed".

When we wish to imply a strong assertion we may use the word **indeed**, it's can have a slightly archaic feel

> Is he a reliable witness?
>
> Indeed not!

We might strongly assert an intention

> Indeed I will be (performing some action)

or determination not to do something

> Indeed I not do that

From that a rather informal, perhaps child-like, stronger assertion

> Indeed and indeed and double indeed I will not (perform action)

And this contracts to

> Deed and deed and double deed ...

An example of this formulation being given in

In Adventures of Tom Sawyer, there is a dialogue going on between Tom and Becky:

> Yes I do, indeed I do. Please let me.
>
> You'll tell.
>
> No I won't—deed and deed and double deed won't.
>
> You won't tell anybody at all.

Also ships do have belts, it's a term for reinforced armour of warships.

Comment: Tom Sawyer has nothing to do with this, it's a different case. Do you realy think "double deed"  in this poem = "double indeed"?

Comment: Indeed I do. The man who is doubly assertive of his position, but may of course be unreliable.

Comment: Double deed I don't!

Comment: [What does double deed mean?]

Comment: As I said, I believe that it means a strong assertion of a position. "do you believe that", "indeed I do" - assertion "deed and double deed I do" - strong assertion

Comment: *A man of double indeed* makes even less sense.

Comment: I don’t know that it _doesn’t_ mean “double indeed,” but this answer certainly doesn’t convince me that it _does_.